# Newb: Assignment: C Prog: saving getchar() input into 2D array

Tags: arrays, c, 2d, getchar

Newb: Learn C - using The C Programming Language - 2nd ed.
I've scoured stackoverflow - can't find a solution.

I'm opening a stream using `getchar()` (its what the manual has me learning.  The stream ends with EOF `<ctrl> z` .  The script looks for a new line and should put each line into a 2D Array (row, width)  Each row ought to hold an entire line of input.

Code runs, stream works.  Doesn't appear to be populating the array though.  Code is far from polished, just trying to get it to work before I polish.  I used exit() simply as a short cut trying to get this to work.  Any ideas?  I added a counter which prints at the end `r` which ought to indicate number of rows created in array... it's zero... making me think array is not being built.  The fate of the universe depends on you!!!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define ROW 1000
#define WIDTH 5000

char arr[ROW][WIDTH] = {0};               // array to store char strings of sentences - each sentence stored in an individual row
int r = 0;                              // initiallizing rows
int i = 0;
char endprog(char arr[ROW][WIDTH]);

int main () {
    
    int c;                               // int variable to accept input - will be copied into arraw
    bool end = true;                           // count the character for each line to iterate through
    
        
    while (end){
    
    for ( i = 0; i < (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i){
    
        if (c == EOF)
            endprog(arr);
            
        arr[r][i] = c;
        
        if (c == '\n'){
                    
            arr[r][i] = c;
            i++;
            r++;                              // new line deterted row incremented to next row - ready for new line
        }
        
        arr[r][i] = '\0';                        // copying input into array at position (row, i)
        
    }
}
}

char endprog(char arr[ROW][WIDTH]){
        
        int j;
    
        for (j = 0; j <= r; j++){                 // iterating through array to print rows of input strings
            printf("R: %d", r);
            printf("%s\n", arr[j]);
        
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Stream is working.
New lines are accepted

Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi
You're my only hope....
^Z
R: 0

--------------------------------
Process exited after 120.8 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: inner `if` condition makes no sense - you already made sure in the `for` condition that `c != \n` ...

Comment: I know.  The example from the book had both, it'll need some cleaning up.  I just can't get the array to populate... i don't think the inner `if` is the culprit... I'll try...

Comment: @OrenIshShalom - that inner `if` did more than what i thought .... so now I'm getting the first letter of each line as the output... `r` value is 62 which seems to be the total number of characters.... one step closer to saving the Republic from the Empire!!

Comment: will your rows *always* contain `WIDTH` entries? or they can be smaller than that value? if they *always* have `WIDTH` entries you're better off with reading your matrix with a double nested loop ...

Comment: no, they can be shorter... WIDTH is just for memory allocation... eventually I'll code for max width..etc...

Comment: @OrenIshShalom why does `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` work?  I'm now trying to compact the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code a bit, I hope this is what you're looking for.
The comments in the code explain almost all the changes I've made to your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* you don't need stdbool.h and stdlib.h for this code*/
#define ROW 1000
#define WIDTH 5000

char arr[ROW][WIDTH] = {0};               // array to store char strings of sentences - each sentence stored in an individual row
int r = 0;                              // initiallizing rows
int i = 0;
void endprog(char arr[ROW][WIDTH]); //the function is void since it's not returning anything

int main () {
int c; // int variable to accept input - will be copied into array
while (1){ //you don't need the for-loop and also the for-loop you've written has wrong logic
    c=getchar();
    if (c == EOF){
        endprog(arr);
        break;
    }
    else{
    arr[r][i] = c;
    i++; //increasing the column by 1
    if (c == '\n'){
        arr[r][i] = '\0'; //since c is '\n', it means the line is completed, so write the NUL character at the end
        i=0;
        r++; //increasing the row by 1 and changing the column to 0 since the next character has to be written in the first (0) index of the next row
    }
    }
}
}

void endprog(char arr[ROW][WIDTH]){
        
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j<r; j++){
            printf("R: %d ", j); //you're supposed to print j, not r
            printf("%s\n", arr[j]);
        }
}
```